# How to cut corner of an image

Tags: ios, swift, image, background, ibdesignable

I make this view with a swift file
[image]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DesignView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var CornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = CornerRadius
    }
  }

}
```

But when i set a image background the image overflow of the view like this :
[image]

I tried to apply the same swift file to my image view like this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DesignImageView: UIImageView {

@IBInspectable var CornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = CornerRadius
    }
  }

}
```

But nothing append so how can i cut the corner without edit my image ?

Comment: view.clipsToBound = true

Comment: @sasquatch Oh it works thank you ^^ 
It has been two hours that I'm on this problem and you solved it in two seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
view.clipsToBound = true
```

Your Image is showing out of its bounds because of its size

From [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds):

> Setting this value to true causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to false, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is false.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code out of your `Class Scope`

```
extension UIView // Almost any Kind of View inherits UIView Ex: UIImageView 
{
    func setCorner(withRadius radius : CGFloat)
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.clipsToBounds = true //your view won't cross the bound
    }
}
```

And use like . .

`DesignImageView.setCorner(withRadius: 5)`